# Tree structures and Java Persistence 2.0

Tags: java, jpa

I have got a few categories. Each category may store an subcategories. For example:

1) Musical instruments

a) Guitars

- Electric guitars
- Acoustic Guitar

b) Pianos

2) Office supplies

- Rulers
- Pencils

I would like view the above data in tree form and I want control the items positions. I use JPA 2.0 and I don't know how I persist the data in the best way. I can resolve the problem in own way, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. So, I'm looking for better solution - a library etc. What should I use?

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic problem.

The solution depends quite a bit on what you want to do with your tree.

The normal solution is to represent the parent-child relationship directly. Your class looks a bit like:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @ManyToOne
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private Set<Category> children;
}
```

And you have a single column in the table which holds the `parent` value.

This approach is simple to understand and implement, and makes navigation around the tree very easy. However, it is rather expensive to answer questions like "what are all the categories somewhere under 'home furnishings'?" or "is 'lilos' a subcategory, at any depth, of 'garden supplies'?".

If you don't mind doing some native SQL, and your database supports recursive common table expressions, then you can do those kinds of queries with that quite easily.

If not, look up [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).